# Getting Flickering Effect When Showing Horizontal RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, flicker, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `Vertical` `RecyclerView`, and this vertical `RecyclerView's` each item contains `Horizontal RecyclerView`. so I have done this and working fine except the performance factor, when I scroll the `Vertical RecyclerView` the vertical list flickers and gives a bad behaviour. I am setting `Adapter` for horizontal `RecyclerView` is inside Vertical `RecyclerView` so each time scrolls I am creating a new adapter and setting the data, actually this causes the performance. Is there any way to optimize this ?

**Code**

```
onBindViewHolder(){
  setHorizontalList(items, horizontalolder);
}

setHorizontalList(ArrayList<Item> items, HorizontalHolder holder){
  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
  adapter.setData(items);
  holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,
                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
  holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have seen similar problem where my inner item background is not properly wrap_content as it should be.

Comment: Yes. I have created adapter for the second RecyclerView inside ViewHolder class. So that it won't create new instances.

Comment: I have done the same but my background goes wonky. Do you mind taking a quick look on my issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823501/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-item-resize-to-last-item

Answer (score 0):

The performance is bad because you set `setHasFixedSize(boolean)` to `true`, this will cause every nested horizontal `RecyclerView` to load all its views when it becomes visible in the vertical `RecyclerView`. Setting the fixed size to `true` is ussualy used to make a `RecyclerView` wrap its content. But to wrap its own content he has to know the size of its content, therefore he has to create all views when becoming visible (to know his max height and width).

Best way to optimize your nested `RecyclerView`s is to not set the fixed size to `true`.But this will probably cause your nested `RecyclerView`s to not be shown completely, because it does not know his height (since different views in a `RecyclerView` can have different heights). One way to solve this is by using a hardcoded height or make your own `CustomRecyclerView` class that extends `RecyclerView` and override the measurements methods.

Comment: not working, the issue is because of creating Adapters inside onBindViewHolder(), thats what i need to optimize.